# Get Geometry object from Envelope in NetTopologySuite

Tags: nettopologysuite

I've built some code to take multiple geometries and merge them into one envelope, but now I need to convert that envelope into a polygon/IGeometry shape that represents that area.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler option:

```
        Envelope envelope = new(95473, 101283, 435552, 445442);
        GeometryFactory factory = new();
        Geometry geometry = factory.ToGeometry(envelope);
```

[Docs](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.Geometries.GeometryFactory.html#NetTopologySuite_Geometries_GeometryFactory_ToGeometry_NetTopologySuite_Geometries_Envelope_)

Answer (score 1):

For others, I ended up just doing the following and it seems to work well.  Feel free to comment if anyone has any opinions:

```c#
public static IGeometry ToGeometry(this Envelope env)
        {
            if (env != null && env.MinX <= env.MaxX && env.MinY <= env.MaxY)
            {
                List<Coordinate> bounds = new List<Coordinate>()
                {
                    new Coordinate(env.MinX,env.MinY),
                new Coordinate(env.MaxX, env.MinY),
                new Coordinate(env.MaxX, env.MaxY),
                new Coordinate(env.MinX, env.MaxY),
                new Coordinate(env.MinX,env.MinY),
            };
                NetTopologySuite.Geometries.LinearRing ring= new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.LinearRing(bounds.ToArray());
                if (ring != null)
                {
                    NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon poly = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon(ring);
                    return poly;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```